# Check Salesforce Field on FormAssembly Submit

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I have a FormAssembly form with some custom js. The code checks the event's available seats and total capacity to determine whether or not space is available; if no seats remain, the user can choose to be redirected to a waitlist. If there are available seats, the user can proceed to fill out the form.

The issue I am having is that some users are taking too long to fill out the form, and the event is filling up afterwards, allowing them to submit and register over capacity. While this wouldn't normally be a problem and could just be handled in Salesforce, the payment connector runs on submit, and payment needs to be verified prior to creating the registration record.

I believe I read the help documentation thoroughly and I'm a bit stuck on what to do here. I thought about potentially adding a Salesforce connector prior and then trying to handle the record creation in Salesforce by setting a field and then looking that up and killing the execution, but I feel that's vastly overcomplicated and I'm missing something very simply.

Could I potentially do something onclick, or is there a better way to go about this?

I also tried to see if I could make use of the save and continue connector, but I couldn't figure out anything viable with that.